# Php Lock files when writte

Tags: php, fwrite, flock

I am testing my code using little database in txt files. The most important problem that I have found is: when users write at the same time into one file. To solve this I am using `flock`.
OS of my computer is windows with xampp installed (*comment this because i understand flocks works fine over linux no windows*) However I need to do this test over linux server.

Actually I have tested my code by loading the same script in 20 windows at the same time. The firsts results works fine, but after test database file appears empty.

**My Code :**

```
$file_db=file("test.db");
$fd=fopen("".$db_name."","w");

if (flock($fd, LOCK_EX)) 
    { 
    ftruncate($fd,0); 
    for ($i=0;$i<sizeof($file_db);$i++)
        {
        fputs($fd,"$file_db[$i]"."\n");
        }
    fflush($fd); 
    flock($fd, LOCK_UN);
    fclose($fd);
    }
else
    {
    print "Db Busy";
    }
```

How it's possible that the script deletes database file content. What is proper way: use `flock` with fixing of existing code or use some other alternative technique of `flock`?

Comment: Why you are trying to invent the wheel? Use database for database.

Comment: Please if you don´t know how works flat file please no answer , because actually many systems use flat files , thank´s , no only exists mysql , regards

Comment: Can you get someone to translate this to English? It's completely unclear what you're asking here.

Comment: The question it´s simple , i use flock when writte over file , but if many users writte the same time , the content of file finally delete , i supose flock no let writte the same time and prevent this issue , i put my script for know if it´s right or no when use flock or something do finally the file erase his content by script , regards

Comment: Nope, still makes no sense. Do you even understand English? You're **not making any sense with that random engrish speak**.

Comment: Ok no problem , my question understand perfectly about use of flock in this script but if you only want speak about language ok , perfect , i pay you no answer more and other people can speak about this , because you only want speak about language or if i speak more or less english of i use perfectly english or no , sure many people can help me , regards

Comment: It was not an answer. That's why it was placed as comment. This question looks like [XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). That's why I was asking "why?". Also there is exists [sqlite](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.sqlite.php) database works without server and stores db using files. Also `flock` has some system restrictions. And, yes, it's hard to understand you. Use dots at the end of a sentence. It's common rule for many languages.

Comment: @Francisco - do you understand that I can't understand what you want? I am not talking about your bad usage of English, I'm trying to tell you that I cannot understand WHAT you want. Now, what sectus said is probably true - XY problem, and given the fact you can't even express what you want makes this question low quality IMO. Voting to close.

Comment: No nice many times , all discuss in this site it´s about language and no for help the people , and the next step everybody put negatives for close account the people , in all time here never put negatives to other people , understand the people can help you in some cases right and in other no right but the most important it´s that in one place created for this , very sad this kind of behaviors for some users , finally all time lost in this and no in search solutions , happy day

Comment: doesn't fputs require 2 arguments?

Comment: @Francisco - if we can't understand you, how can we help you? Are you able to understand what I'm trying to say?

Comment: You're not making any coherent sense to any of us.

Comment: @Francisco what is the content of test.db?

Comment: first of all change to this: `fputs($fd, $file_db[$i] . "\n");` fputs first parameter is a file handler. And you not close the handler, if there are no `flock`, but you opened that.

Answer (score 0):

I have re-wrote the script using @lolka_bolka's answer and it works. So in answer to your question, the file `$db_name` could be empty if the file `test.db` is empty.

Comment: No the db no empty and fputs i forget put the first argument because i writte here the script sorry i put now well , regards

Answer (score 0):

[`ftruncate`](http://php.net/ftruncate) after [`fopen`](http://php.net/fopen) with "w" is useless.

[`file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) function

> Returns the file in an array. Each element of the array corresponds to a line in the file, with the newline still attached. Upon failure, file() returns FALSE.

You do not have to add additional end of line symbol.

[`flock`](http://php.net/flock) function

> PHP supports a portable way of locking complete files in an advisory way (which means all accessing programs have to use the same way of locking or it will not work).

It means that `file` function not affected by the lock. It means that     `$file_db=file("test.db");` could read file while other process somewhere between `ftruncate($fd,0);` and `fflush($fd);`. So, you need read file content inside lock.

```
$db_name = "file.db";
$fd = fopen($db_name, "r+"); // w changed to r+ for getting file resource but not truncate it

if (flock($fd, LOCK_EX))
    {
    $file_db = file($db_name); // read file contents while lock obtained
    ftruncate($fd, 0);
    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($file_db); $i++)
        {
        fputs($fd, "$file_db[$i]");
        }
    fflush($fd);
    flock($fd, LOCK_UN);
    }
else
    {
    print "Db Busy";
    }
fclose($fd); // fclose should be called anyway
```

P.S. you could test this script using console

```
$  for i in {1..20}; do php 'file.php' >> file.log 2>&1 & done
```